# Remove next div with JavaScript, without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

anyone can help me on a things , I have in a page once `<nav class='test'>` and below a `<div>` without any class/id, I want to hide/remove `<div>` element which is in next of `<nav>` tag , I can do `$('.test').next().remove();` but strictly jQuery is not allowed , please give me any trick of JavaScript or CSS, Please note that , i haven’t access to edit any html code only i can add js/css.

Code is looking like this:-

```
<body class='home'>
    <nav class='test'></nav>
    <div>Want to remove this elements</div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with css [adjacent sibling or next-sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

```js
var ele = document.querySelector('.test + *')

ele.remove();

// or for older browser
// ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele)
// or
// document.body.removeChild(ele)
```

```html
<body class='home'>
  <nav class='test'></nav>
  <div>Want to remove this elements</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `nextElementSibling`:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('nav').nextElementSibling;
document.body.removeChild(el);
```

```html
<body class='home'>
    <nav class='test'>d</nav>
    <div>Want to remove this elements</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it with CSS by selecting the [adjacent sibling selector (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), and setting it's display property to `none`:

```css
.test + div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body class='home'>
    <nav class='test'>Nav</nav>
    <div>Want to remove this elements</div>
</body>
```